# Excel - Dynamically Name the Top left Cell of a Table after filter's

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, datatable, named-ranges

When you filter a table, the rows consolidate so the location of what I want to select continually changes. I am using two filters right now so I'm not sure how to dynamically name that the cell that is on top each time.

Comment: look into [range.specialcells()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky - but as Scott suggests the key is to use SpecialCells - and the **xlCellTypeVisible** constant

You must also let Excel know what offset your data is starting from - and take into account the filter header if there is one.

This code should work for you if you modify the constants to fit your example.

It's best to include your own code in the future so we're not guessing.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Const FilterHeaderRow As Integer = 1
    Const StartOfDataRows As Integer = 2
    Const DataOffset As Integer = StartOfDataRows - FilterHeaderRow
    
    Const CellFilteredLocation = 1
    
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(StartOfDataRows, StartOfDataRows).Select
    Debug.Print Selection.Row ' ===> will only display second actual row
    
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(DataOffset).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(CellFilteredLocation, CellFilteredLocation).Select
    Debug.Print Selection.Row ' ===> Actual first filtered row

End Sub
```